# "error LINK2019: unresolved..."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lapack, blas, armadillo

I'm trying to compile a test program using Visual Studio 2012 written in C++, the program computes the inverse of an arbitrary matrix using the [Armadillo linear algebra](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library. This requires that you enable LAPACK in Armadillo's `config.h` file and link to the libraries/dlls in the project's properties (which I've done).

I'm compiling for a 64bit release so I've downloaded the suitable BLAS/LAPACK libraries from [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/) and have linked the VS project against them. Having done all this I'm still getting link errors whilst trying to use Armadillo's `inv(...)` method as follows:

```
1>Matrix.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgetrf_ referenced in function "public: static double __cdecl arma::auxlib::det_lapack<double>(class arma::Mat<double> const &,bool)" (??$det_lapack@N@auxlib@arma@@SANAEBV?$Mat@N@1@_N@Z)
1>Matrix.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgetri_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getri<double>(long *,double *,long *,long *,double *,long *,long *)" (??$getri@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAJPEAN00100@Z)
```

Can anyone give me a slight indication as to what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure you added the library in Additional Dependencies" under *Project -> (Project Name) Properties -> Linker -> Input* ?

Comment: Yes, I've got `libblas.lib` and `liblapack.lib` referenced there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples provided with Armadillo should compile out of the box. Open the project files in the examples/example1_win32 folder. You may want to simply use them as a starting point for your code.

Alternatively, this site might be useful: [Armadillo with BLAS and LAPACK in 64 bit Visual C++ projects](http://www.ru.is/kennarar/sigurdurh/Armadillo64hack.html)

Using 64 bit LAPACK and BLAS is considerably faster than the 32 bit versions.  You may also want to look into using Intel MKL, which provides high-speed multi-core implementation of LAPACK.

Comment: Thanks, the example projects compile successfully but the executable doesn't run `Unable to start program ...example1_win32.exe. The system file cannot find the file specified`. Thanks for the link, I'll see if it works

Comment: Following that step-by-step guide worked, thank you very much!